# Optimization for MySQL Query - Fetch PHP

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, fetch

```
<?php function ss($s1, $s2, $s3, $s4, $s5, $s6) {
  $sonucArray = array("alti" => 0, "bes" => 0, "dort" => 0, "uc" => 0, "iki" => 0);
  $sayiArray = array($s1, $s2, $s3, $s4, $s5, $s6);
  $sayiArraySql = join(',',$sayiArray);  
  $query = mysql_query("select * from loto where 
                                  s1 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                                  s2 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                                  s3 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                                  s4 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                                  s5 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                                  s6 in ($sayiArraySql)");

  while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      $controlArray = array($record["s1"],$record["s2"],$record["s3"],$record["s4"],$record["s5"],$record["s6"]);
      $diffArray = array_diff($sayiArray,$controlArray);

      if (count($diffArray) == 0)
          $sonucArray["alti"]++;
      else if (count($diffArray) == 1)
          $sonucArray["bes"]++;
      else if (count($diffArray) == 2)
          $sonucArray["dort"]++;
      else if (count($diffArray) == 3)
          $sonucArray["uc"]++;
      else if (count($diffArray) == 4)
          $sonucArray["iki"]++;      
  }

  return $sonucArray;
}
```

mysql_fetch_array; using too much CPU and no fast!

**"s1-s2-s3-s4-s5-s6" are integers.**

Instead what should be a code? I know php insufficient. Some people suggested me to "mysql_fetch_row"  but I could not write to it by adapting

what should I?

Comment: If your query is too slow, try indexing those columns you are searching by.

Comment: Those columns was indexed. There are many query processing

Answer (score 0):

Your function using mysql_fetch_row :

```
<?php 
function ss($s1, $s2, $s3, $s4, $s5, $s6) 
{
    $sonucArray = array("alti" => 0, "bes" => 0, "dort" => 0, "uc" => 0, "iki" => 0);
    $sayiArray = array($s1, $s2, $s3, $s4, $s5, $s6);
    $sayiArraySql = join(',',$sayiArray);  
    $query = mysql_query("select s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6 from loto where 
                              s1 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                              s2 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                              s3 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                              s4 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                              s5 in ($sayiArraySql) or
                              s6 in ($sayiArraySql)");

    while ($record = mysql_fetch_row($query)) 
    {
        $controlArray = array($record[0],$record[1],$record[2],$record[3],$record[4],$record[5]);
        $diffArray = array_diff($sayiArray,$controlArray);

        if (count($diffArray) == 0)
            $sonucArray["alti"]++;
        else if (count($diffArray) == 1)
            $sonucArray["bes"]++;
        else if (count($diffArray) == 2)
            $sonucArray["dort"]++;
        else if (count($diffArray) == 3)
            $sonucArray["uc"]++;
        else if (count($diffArray) == 4)
            $sonucArray["iki"]++;      
    }
    return $sonucArray;
}
```

mysql_fetch_row is just using integers instead of fields name as index in the array returned. $record[0] will be the first field in the row according to your sql request. That's why i write each field name in the request and not just *, to make sure the order corresponds.

Hope that helped.